# after submit the form the vue reset all the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      usrName: null,
      pass1: null,
      pass2: null,
      regState: {stateCode:-1},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    register: function () {
        this.axios.post("/login/", { baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000', usrName: this.usrName, passWord: this.pass1 }).then((response)=>{
          console.log(response.data)
          this.$store.state.sysDecision.usrDecision = 2
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>


<template>
  <XAIHeader :registerActive="true"></XAIHeader>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="w-50 mx-auto pt-5" style="padding-bottom: 400px;">
      <h5 class="mb-3">register</h5>
      <div>
        <label class="form-label">user name</label>
        <input v-model="usrName" type="text" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="form-label">pass word </label>
        <input v-model="pass1" type="current-password" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="form-label">repeat pass word</label>
        <input v-model="pass2" type="new-password" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3">
        <button @click="register" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">register</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    {{ this.$store.state.sysDecision.usrDecision}}
  </div>
</template>
```

I try to send a post request with axios, the backend webserver respond json response correctly. But after receiving the data, but the data in vue reset to the initial value quickly and even the data in vuex is reset to the default initial value. How can I keep the previous data after post the form?

Comment: My assumption is, you should remove the `type="submit"` from your button as submit type causes the page to reload which can be the reason to reset the data. Also, you don't need this if you are writing the submit functionality by calling a function already.

Comment: Either don't use type="submit", or use `@submit` on form itself

Comment: I have tried remove the `type="submit"` and send the register request many times，but the page reload and the backend django break down after I send register request.@Neha Soni.@Estus Flask.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by replacing the `<form></form>`  with `<div></div>`. It seems if use `<form></form>` tag, the page reloading is inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

@submit.prevent="register"

try this maybe work.

```
<template>
  <XAIHeader :registerActive="true"></XAIHeader>
  <div class="container">
    <form @submit.prevent="register" class="w-50 mx-auto pt-5" style="padding-bottom: 400px;">
      <h5 class="mb-3">register</h5>
      <div>
        <label class="form-label">user name</label>
        <input v-model="usrName" type="text" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="form-label">pass word </label>
        <input v-model="pass1" type="current-password" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="form-label">repeat pass word</label>
        <input v-model="pass2" type="new-password" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">register</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    {{ this.$store.state.sysDecision.usrDecision}}
  </div>
</template>
```

reference here
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers

Answer (score -1):

After submit response the form data you need to make your v-model data to null, then your form will be reset.

> this.usrName = null

Comment: This is not what OP asked.